# SQL query column names in datagridview

Tags: sql, datagridview

I have two tables `test1 { id, name }` and `test2 { id, name, family }` and I write this query:

```
SELECT dbo.test1.*, dbo.test2.*
FROM dbo.test1
CROSS JOIN dbo.test2
```

but in datagridview1, I want to show the fields (on header) like this:

`test1.id    test1.name   test2.id   test2.name  test2.family`,

but instead they are displayed like this

`id    name    id    name    family`

which changes are needed for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select the columns individually, and use the `as` keyword:

```
SELECT dbo.test1.id as test1id, dbo.test2.id as test2id ...
FROM dbo.test1
CROSS JOIN dbo.test2
```

Comment: the `as` keyword is not required, but may make things more readable

Comment: or you can use the dot with square brackets I think, `dbo.test1.id as [test1.id]`. But you'd be better off selecting and renaming the columns in your data grid control.

Comment: thanks for your attention.if i have more tables that i want to cross join them and i want to show each tabale with fileds like this: tb1.filed1  tb1.filed2 tb2.filed1 ..... should i do?

Comment: i mean how can i select fileds with details like it's tabale's name.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you can change the caption of the grid columns as you like. You can also reorder/hide/sort columns as you like.

Answer (score 3):

I would write the select like:

```
select t1.id as "test1.Id", 
       t1.name as "test1.Name", 
       t2.id as "test2.Id", 
       t2.name as "test2.Name", 
       t2.family as "Test2.Family" 
from test1 t1, test2 t2
```

But with that query you will get a cartesian product, if you don't add a proper Where Clause.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to alias the columns?

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS [test1.id],
    t1.name AS [test1.name] ,
    t2.id AS [test2.id], 
    t2.name AS [test2.name] ,
    t2.family AS [test2.family]
FROM dbo.test1 t1
CROSS JOIN dbo.test2 t2
```

As the names you want don't meet the standard rules for identifiers they need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Bad code is bad. However, I would do it as @Scoregraphic mentioned. Even if all of your columns come back as `co1; col1; col1`, you can change the order and labeling. Use the properties for the columns in the DataGridView.